# Problems going back and forth between scenes (Sprite Kit)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, sprite-kit

I am new to the iOS platform and have written an app using Sprite Kit and Xamarin. To transition between scenes I am using NavigationController.PushViewController with a "Back" button on the new scene to return. This works fine.

My problem occurs when I go back and forth between the original scene and next scene about 3 times. The frame rate (and overall application) slows to a crawl, and depending on which scenes, will hard crash. This happens only on device and not in the simulator. My gut instinct says I'm leaking memory somewhere / not cleaning up properly, so I have just started getting up-to-speed with Instruments. Note that each scene has about 5-8 images on it.

Questions:

- What is the proper way to clean-up after transitioning out of a scene back to the previous one? I am explicitly calling RemoveAllActions() and RemoveAllChildren() to ensure clean-up.
- What is my best strategy when using Instruments? I've only just begun to experiment with an Allocations trace, but there are a lot of allocations and knowing what to look for is challenging.

Any help is appreciated. I am considering dumping Sprite Kit altogether since my app doesn't really need it (I wanted to experiment) and because it has been a challenge building the app with all kinds of deep crashes (e.g. SKShapeNode, which is very problematic).

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to remove everything.  If you switch back to the scene check if its init and do nothing if it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have a flag that bypasses node creation if we are already in an initialized state. As a result, the creation code gets bypassed when popping the scene off the navigation controller stack. Excessive memory use is my best guess right now as to why the frame rate takes a severe hit (60fps down to 2fps), so I am still wondering the right way to clean things up.